# reference request: writing intervals of totally-ordered sets in a "nice" way

Tags: reference-request, notation, order-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a totally-ordered set.

We need to introduce some symbolism and terminology, which is all very natural and intuitive.  If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Omega$ we write $A<B$ whenever $a<b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  By an **interval** of $\Omega$, we mean any subset $I$ such that there exist sets $A$ and $B$ with $A<I<B$ and $\Omega=A\cup I\cup B$.  In the special case where $A=\emptyset$, the interval $I$ is called an **initial segment** of $\Omega$.

It is desirable to write intervals of $\Omega$ as we might write intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus, we say that an interval $I$ of $\Omega$ is of **real form** if it can be written in one of the following ways for some $a,b\in\Omega$:
$$(-\infty,b):=\{x\in\Omega:x<b\}$$
$$(-\infty,b]:=\{x\in\Omega:x\leq b\}$$
$$(a,b):=\{x\in\Omega:a<x<b\}$$
and so on, also for $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b]$, $(a,\infty)$, and $[a,\infty)$, defined in the obvious ways.

Unfortunately, intervals of $\Omega$ need not always have real form.  Consider for instance the case $\Omega=[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ endowed with the usual ordering.  Then $[0,1)$ is an interval, but $1\notin\Omega$ and so it can't be written in real form.  On the other hand, due to the fact that $\Omega\subseteq[0,2]$ in this case, we can still write the interval $[0,1)$ very nicely.

**Fact.**  For any totally-ordered set $\Omega$, there exists a superset $\Gamma\supseteq\Omega$ which is endowed with a "compatible" total order (in the sense that $x<y$ in $\Omega$ implies $x<y$ in $\Gamma$), and such that every interval of $\Gamma$ has real form.

This is not hard to show.  If $b\in\Omega$ we define
$$I_b:=(-\infty,b].$$
Let $\Gamma$ denote the set of all initial segments of $\Omega$.  Then $\subseteq$ is a total order on $\Gamma$ compatible with the order on $\Omega$, and the map $b\mapsto I_b$ is an injection from $\Omega$ into $\Gamma$ which means we can identify $\Omega$ with a subset of $\Gamma$.  It is straightforward to see that every interval of $\Gamma$ is of real form.

**Question 1.**  Has this been discussed in the literature?  If so, does anyone have a reference?

**Question 2.**  The term "real form" sounds unsatisfying, but I can't think of anything better.  Is there already a term for this in the literature?  Or just a better suggestion from you guys?

Thanks!

Comment: A general term for interval is order convex which can also be used with partial orders.

Comment: As a matter of fact,  a set in a connected linear order is order convex iff it is an interval.  So the real forms are the connected orders.

Comment: @WilliamElliot connected in the order topology?

Comment: Yes............